# Typical Practice for external application config

Tags: configuration, powershell

I have a C# cmdlet(1) that uses "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings" to get database connection strings necessary for some stored procedures used in the cmdlet(1). If another application instantiates an instance of the cmdlet(1) class object, then calls a method on the class that use a stored procedure an error is thrown because the other application/project(2)'s app.config does not have the same app.config settings.

I think application(2)'s config should be updated with the same settings needed basically copying the connection string from the cmdlet(1).

My question is whether the approach is typical and best practice or should the cmdlet(1) be responsible for all calls that depend on its own app.config settings.

Comment: `App.Config` is not designed to pass dynamically-changed settings from one application to another in the manner you described.  You'll have to figure out another way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I updated my question as it was not clear I believe,  the settings would be the same, not changed. Project(dll) 2 would just add a new key value pair to its config, unless I am misunderstanding.

Comment: I think the question you should really be asking is whether or not it's a good idea to be passing database credentials over the wire.

Comment: Ah, thanks @RobertHarvey I think that answers my question, no not a good idea.